# How to Xpath from Form

Tags: html, forms, web-scraping, xpath

I have html code like:

```
<form class="variations_form cart" action="https://example.com/name-of-product" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="386" data-product_variations="[{&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_pa_czas-realizacji&quot;:&quot;24h&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&lt;p class=\&quot;stock out-of-stock\&quot;&gt;Brak w magazynie&lt;\/p&gt;\n&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;dimensions&quot;:{&quot;length&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]">
```

I would like to extract "Brak w magazynie".

I have tried xpath:

```
//*[text() = 'Brak w magazynie']
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea how to do it? :)

Comment: Element HTML you sharing doesn't contain that text. You should not search for element with known text if you want to extract that text. can you share a link to that web page?

Comment: The form attribute "data-product_variations" has that string of characters. If this string occurs, the product is out of stock on the website.

Comment: So, you want to select products with this indication on the page? OK, I will update my answer

Comment: Can you help me @Prophet with this case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71513109/how-to-xpath-from-script-tag ?

Comment: I saw that your question. I'm not sure I understand it / can help there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XPath expressions to locate this element:

```
//form[@class='variations_form cart']
```

Or

```
//form[@action='https://example.com/name-of-product']
```

Or

```
//form[@action='https://example.com/name-of-product' and @class='variations_form cart']
```

And then extract the found element text
**UPD**
If you want to select such elements containing `Brak w magazynie` in their `data-product_variations` attribute you can use XPath like this:

```
//form[@class='variations_form cart' and(contains(@data-product_variations,'Brak w magazynie')) ]
```

Or

```
//form[@action='https://example.com/name-of-product' and contains(@data-product_variations,'Brak w magazynie')]
```

Comment: No, I can't. I have a list of products. Some of them have "Brak w magazynie" and are out of stock but other don't have that string and are available.

Comment: I see, please check the updated answer

Comment: It works :D Thank you very much :) You made my day :)